# is there any simple way to print array object in xcode 13.1 when using swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using swift to write a music player plugin, now I want to check the music queue array in xcode 13.1. what I am doing is using lldb in xcode terminal like this:

```
(lldb) po queue
▿ 2 elements
  ▿ 0 : <MusicMetadata: 0x600003e41c00>
  ▿ 1 : <MusicMetadata: 0x600003e71620>
```

this command only output the element top level, but now I want to check the element detail info, then I tried like this:

```
(lldb) p print(String(data: try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: queue, options: .prettyPrinted), encoding: .utf8)!)
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: internal ObjC exception breakpoint(-5)..
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

is there any simple way to check the array? Why could not view the array object in Xcode like Intellij Idea? I also tried like this:

```
(lldb) po print(queue)
[music_player.MusicMetadata, music_player.MusicMetadata]
0 elements
```

Comment: What's `MusicMetadata` ? Are you looking for `CustromStringConnvertible`? Use `e` instead of `po`?

Comment: Why would you ever `p print`? To see a thing, `po` that thing, not a `print` statement. If you can't `po` the thing, fix the thing so you can.

Answer (score 1):

Your `MusicMetadata` type would need to conform to `CustomStringConvertable` in order for the `po` command to output anything useful in this situation. This protocol is simply a way for you to define how your `MusicMetadata` type is presented as a string.

```
struct MusicMetadata {
    let title: String
    let artist: String
}

extension MusicMetadata: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        "title: \(title), artist: \(artist)"
    }
}

let testMusic = MusicMetadata(title: "fooTitle", artist: "fooArtist")
let testMusic2 = MusicMetadata(title: "barTitle", artist: "barTitle")

let queue = [
    MusicMetadata(title: "fooTitle", artist: "fooArtist"),
    MusicMetadata(title: "barTitle", artist: "barTitle"),
]

queue.description // "[title: fooTitle, artist: fooArtist, title: barTitle, artist: barTitle]"
```

Since your `queue` is an array (and therefore conforms to the [Sequence](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence) protocol, you have several ways to output your a string representation of your `MusicMetadata` value:

If you're unable to add the conformance and you're simply wanting to verify one or more of the properties on the value/object, you can use the fact that the array is a [Sequence](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence) and use `map` to convert the array of `MusicMetadata` types to an array of only one property, and then convert them from output from there.

Extending the example above, since the `title` property is a `String`, you can simply use the `joined(separator:)` method to output

```
po queue.map { $0.title }.joined(separator: ", ") // fooTitle, barTitle
```